# Why in iOS, we cannot declare a "UIAcceleration accelerationCurrent;" instance variable in the ViewController class?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer

If the event handler for Accelerometer takes a `UIAcceleration *` in the following:

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
            didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
```

then if `ViewController` has an instance variable:

```
UIAcceleration accelerationCurrent;
```

Then in order to remember the acceleration as a current state, I used

```
accelerationCurrent = *acceleration;
```

in the Accelerometer event handler.   But the instance variable declaration in the `.h` file gave error as "Interface type cannot be statically allocated".

I thought `UIAcceleration` is just 3 doubles: x, y, z, so if we can use `CGPoint aPoint` there, how come we cannot use `UIAcceleration accelerationCurrent`, and how can we keep the acceleration without copying the x, y, z individually but use one `UIAcceleration` object?  (if we declare a pointer instead, and copy the pointer (the reference), then upon leaving the accelerometer event handler, the pointer may point to an illegal memory space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though `UIAcceleration` has only four data members (x, y, z, and a timestamp) it is not a `struct`, and therefore it does not let you refer to it statically (i.e. you need to use a pointer). This is in contrast to `CGPoint`, which is a C `struct`, so you can use it both through a pointer or without a pointer.

Unfortunately, there is no way around copying the values in which you are interested: you are absolutely right that once the thread leaves your handler, `UIAcceleration` object may get reused behind your back. `UIAcceleration` does not conform to copying protocol either, so you would need to write that copy routine yourself.

Comment: I suppose we will need to copy x, y, z individually, or typedef our own struct to do a copy?  Using `CMAcceleration` should work because it is a struct? but it won't allow either

Comment: @動靜能量 Yes, `CMAcceleration` fits the bill perfectly. You can store it instead of three individual items (unless you also need a timestamp, which it does not sound like you do). You need to write a conversion from `UIAcceleration` to `CMAcceleration` yourself, though, so your code would look like `cmAccelCurrent = CopyToCmAcceleration(acceleration)` or `CopyToCmAcceleration(&cmAccelCurrent, acceleration)`.